# How do i sort this based on its DateTransaction using dropdown list?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, sorting

I'm new to PHP and i need your help please. :)
So basically, I want to sort this table using a dropdown list based on its DateTransaction column but the choices are the months from January to December.

so I have this code

```
           <?php
           $q = intval($_GET['q']);

           $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','duday2.0');
           if (!$con) {
             die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
           }

           mysqli_select_db($con,"ajax_demo");
           $sql="
           SELECT transaction.totalAmountDue, transaction.DateTransaction, transaction.condition, transaction.reasonVoid, sales.productID, sales.quantity, sales.subtotal, sales.transactionID, sales.productID, sales.quantity, sales.subtotal FROM transaction INNER JOIN sales ON sales.transactionID = transaction.transactionID  WHERE transaction.transactionID = '".$q."'";
           $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql)
           or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($con));

           echo '<table class= "t_data" border=1 cellspacing=5>';
           echo '<thead style="padding:1px">';
           echo '<tr>
           <td height="5" width="2000" align="left" colspan=10><strong><font color=white>TransactionID</td>
           <td height="5" width="2000" align="left" colspan=10><strong><font color=white>DateTransaction</td>
           <td height="5" width="2000" align="left" colspan=10><strong><font color=white>Condition</td>
           <td height="5" width="2000" align="left" colspan=10><strong><font color=white>Product ID</td>
           <td height="5" width="2000" align="left" colspan=10><strong><font color=white>Quantity</td>
           <td height="5" width="2000" align="left" colspan=10><strong><font color=white>Sub Total</td>
           </thead>
           </tr>';

           while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
           {
             echo '<tr>
                <td width="100px" align="left" colspan=10>'.$row['transactionID'].'</td>
                <td width="100px" align="left" colspan=10>'.$row['DateTransaction'].'</td>
                <td width="100px" align="left" colspan=10>'.$row['condition'].'</td>
                <td width="100px" align="left" colspan=10>'.$row['productID'].'</td>
                <td width="100px" align="left" colspan=10>'.$row['quantity'].'</td>
                <td width="100px" align="left" colspan=10>'.$row['subtotal'].'</td>
                </tr>';
           }
           echo "</table>";

           mysqli_close($con);
           ?>
```

and this code

```
    <script>
            function showReport(str) {
              if (str=="") {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
                return;
              } 
              if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {

                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
              } else { 
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
              }
              xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
                  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
              }
              xmlhttp.open("GET","getReport.php?q="+str,true);
              xmlhttp.send();
            }
            </script>


            <form>
            <select name="months" onchange="showReport(this.value)">

            <option Selected>--Select Month--</option>
            <option value="">January</option>
            <option value="">February</option>
            <option value="">March</option>
            <option value="">April</option>
            <option value="">May</option>
            <option value="">June</option>
            <option value="">July</option>
            <option value="">August</option>
            <option value="">September</option>
            <option value="">October</option>
            <option value="">November</option>
            <option value="">December</option>
            </select>

            </form>
```

and I don't know what to put in values to sort the date by months.

TIA.

Comment: could you please provide some more details on how you expect the data to be rendered in page, because if you apply the dropdown and it would act as a filter rather than a sortable component. E.g. If you select January then you would like to filter records based on the month selected, is this the requirement which you want? If not could you specify some more details on it.

Comment: yes that is exactly what i need. but my DateTransaction column have data like this.. 2014-01-28 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Decorate the table as below:

```
<table id="tblRecords">
<thead>
    <tr>
        // your header code goes here...
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Change the dropdown value fields as below:

```
<select name="months" onchange="showReport(this.value)">
        <option Selected>--Select Month--</option>
        <option value="1">January</option>
        <option value="2">February</option>
        ...
```

Replace your script as below:

```
<script>
        function showReport(str) {
          if (str=="") {
            document.getElementById('myTable').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].innerHTML="";
            return;
          } 
          if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {

            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
          } else { 
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }
          xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
              document.getElementById('myTable').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
          }
          xmlhttp.open("GET","getReport.php?q="+str,true);// here str is the value field of the dropdown selected
          xmlhttp.send();
        }
        </script>
```

In getReport.php, write the query and generate the rows in a string as below:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE MONTH(dateStart) = {$m} // where $m is the month which you selected in the dropdown list as passed through ajax

$str = ''
       while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
       {
            $str .= '<tr>'
            // your columns text
            $str .= '</tr>'
        }
        return $str;
```

Every time there is an ajax call, new rows will be created based on filter and table will be populated.

Hope this helps :)